# What is this attachment that is connected to my home's main water line?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I woke up yesterday morning to water spraying out of the bottom of this attachment. After having a mini panic attack I shut the main off. I waited about 30 mins before turning the main back on and the water stopped spraying out and everything appears to be fine now. Is this some kind of back-flow preventer or pressure regulator? Can someone explain to me what the purpose of this attachment is?

[image: main water attachment]

**Edit** Here are some more photos of the setup.

[image: bottom part of attachment]

[image: left side of attachment]

[image: whole system]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the left end and the bottom ([edit] your post and include them there)? Those _look_ like fittings of some sort, but it's hard to tell for sure. Others will likely be along soon who will know more than I do.

Comment: Thanks! I added more photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a valve installed to tap off of your main line for an irrigation system, then either abandoned or never used. The part on the far left is a knurled knob with a slot in it, probably designed for using a special "keyed" handle so that it could not be accidentally turned off and have your landscaping die. The seals likely failed from never being used, then managed to re-seal when you turned off the pressure. Expect it to fail again now, sooner than later. You should have it replaced or removed if you are never going to use it.

Comment: Do you think this is polybutylene tubing?

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I added more photos if that helps. I can tell you that I had a new sprinkler system installed last year which you can see in the last photo. If that attachment is from the old sprinkler system, it's ok to cap/remove it?

Comment: Yes, I would assume so, just remove the valve and leave the stub of pipe it is attached to capped off. Likely that original setup didn't leave room for an anti-siphon valve, which is what you showed in the follow up photo for the new sprinkler system. So when the new one was put in, they tapped in further upstream and just abandoned the old connection. It also looks like the older connection was smaller pipe, which may have restricted your flow for sprinklers.